# Debugging connection timeouts using strace?

Tags: linux, eclipse, debug, lsof, strace

I'm trying to figure out why is Eclipse spinning, so I decided to fire up strace.

I found the eclipse process using:

```
$ ps ax | grep java
 5546 ?        Sl    19:04 /usr/bin/java ... [arguments omitted]
```

By running `strace` on this process, I see that it's waiting on another process:

```
$ sudo strace -p 5546
Process 5546 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x7f6c416679d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 5547, NULL^C <unfinished ...>
Process 5546 detached
```

Interestingly, process 5547 doesn't appear in `ps` (can anyone tell me why?), but I can `strace` it. It is repeatedly spitting out a lot of EAGAIN failures (with the occasional success)

```
read(16, 0x7f6c41664d10, 16)            = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(15, 0x7f6c3815f2e4, 4096, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {67410, 357843264}) = 0
poll([{fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=68, events=POLLIN}, {fd=128, events=POLLIN}, {fd=69, events=POLLIN}], 5, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
read(16, 0x7f6c41664cb0, 16)            = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(15, 0x7f6c3815f2e4, 4096, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
...
```

Judging from the output, it looks like it is polling the file descriptors 16, 15, 68, 128 and 69. Particularly, the `EAGAIN` errors are coming from fds 15 and 6, as seen from the `read(2)` and `recvfrom(2)` calls.

How do I find more information on those fds? I tried `lsof -p 5547` but no output is printed. I suspect these are sockets that are open to some website, but why it is spinning in a tight loop with `EAGAIN` failures is puzzling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some PIDs are not listed because they belong to *threads*. `htop` can show them if you press <kbd>Shift+H</kbd> (and optionally <kbd>T</kbd> for tree view), but `lsof` wants the PID of the main process. (All pthreads in a process share file descriptors, anyway.) You can also take a look in `/proc/5546/fd/` and `/proc/5546/task/`.

EAGAIN is normal for non-blocking I/O; for example, it is returned by `read()` when there's no data to read. See "ERRORS" in *read(2)*, *write(2)* and so on. Some of these fd's are likely connections to the X11 server – non-blocking I/O is used by the X11 client libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I have now become a tiny bit better at debugging :-)

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be less resource intensive if the sockets use callbacks to know when data has arrived?

Comment: @jabalsad: `poll()` is already used for that. I don't know, though, why it returns `{fd=16, events=POLLIN}` if there's nothing to read() from it..

Comment: Do you mean that when `poll()` is called, the application should know that data is available for read or not?. If so, why is a `read()` still performed when there is no data available?

Comment: Nevermind, your added comment answered my question.

Comment: @jabalsad: Ah, I just noticed a few things. One, the fd's displayed in strace output are actually *input* to poll(), not its output (as would be the case with select()), so naturally strace shows all polled fd's. Second, `poll()` returns 0, meaning "timeout, no events", so the fd's really don't have any new data; the library probably just fails to check the return code properly.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter to `futex(2)` is not necessarily a process ID, the manual says it's `futex(uaddr, op, val, timeout, ...)`, and that if op is `FUTEX_WAIT`, it "atomically verifies that the futex address *uaddr* still contains the value *val*, and sleeps awaiting FUTEX_WAKE on this futex address. [When] *timeout* is NULL, the call blocks indefinitely."

In your case, it sounds like the process 5546 was sitting there waiting for something -- presumably its thread 5547 or something related, but we can't know exactly what for sure based only on this -- to write that number at the specified memory address.

Note also that you can see threads by using `ps -eLf` or similar.